# stopping a fixed position when it reaches to almost the bottom

Tags: jquery, html, css, scrolltop

I have read quite a few threads on stackoverflow about this situation and tried their ways either with jquery or html /css but mine just keeps on not working the way wanted.  Can someone please give me a hand?

My html

```
<div id="product-summary-position">
    <div id="product-fixed">
        <div id="product-summary">
            <header>Product Summary</header>
            <div class="price" name="product-summary-price">$0.00</div>
            <header>Have Questions?</header>
            <p>Call our Product Experts<br> 1-877-270-3311</p>
            <button class="btn-reset">Reset</button>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

my css

```
#product-summary-position{float: right;
    height: 185px;
    width: 185px;}

div#product-summary {
    font-family: 'roboto';
    height: 230px;
    width: 185px;
    background-color: #2A0092;
    border-radius: 5px;
    text-align: center;
    color: #FFF;
    top: 250px;
}

div#product-fixed {
    position: fixed;
}
```

I have a footer that's approximate 400px each time I scroll down the product summary would overlap the footer.  I tried using what I can find online but couldn't figure out how to make it work properly.

Thanks in advance.

Edit : [jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/et4891/rnxL2v4y/1/)

Comment: Can you make a fiddle?

Comment: @S.Eberl added, it's something like that and I don't want the fixed position to pass the `hr` where it says footer

Comment: So how do you want the page to work? When the bottom edge of the footer reaches the top edge of the footer, how is the scrolling suppose to work? Do you want the product summary panel to start scrolling along with the rest of the footer?

Comment: Maybe this could help. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/31355400/footer-slider-implementation?noredirect=1#comment50692757_31355400

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try [this](http://jsfiddle.net/uum6gn93/7/).

---

**Solution**

Change yours HTML to this:

```
<div id="product-summary-position">
    <div id="product-fixed">
        <div id="product-summary">
            <header>Product Summary</header>
            <div class="price" name="product-summary-price">$0.00</div>
            <header>Have Questions?</header>
            <p>Call our Product Experts
                <br>1-877-270-3311</p>
            <button class="btn-reset">Reset</button>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>

<footer id="wholeFooter">
    <!-- move entire footer to separate block element -->
    <div class="footer2">
        ...
    </div>
    <div class="footer2">
        ...
    </div>
</footer>
```

And, javascript:

```
var doc = $(document); 

doc.scroll(function () {
     // make sure to wrap yours entire footer in some css selector
    var footer = $('#wholeFooter');
    var p = $('#product-fixed');
    var s = $('#product-summary-position');

    var top = doc.scrollTop() + s.offset().top * 2 + p.height();
    var footerTop = footer.offset().top;

    var offset = footerTop - top;

    if (offset < 0) {
        p.css({'margin-top': '' + offset + 'px'});
    } else {
        p.css({'margin-top': 0});
    }

});
```

**Upd.***

Separate "fixed" class was unnecessary.

Comment: Thanks, this works well I just had to change the `* 2` to `+ 20` for a better position which is easy adjustment.